# How To: URL Rewrite & HTML Link Within Same Page?

Tags: php, html, url-rewriting, hyperlink

I want a user to click on link of www.domain.com/how-it-works

**My URL Rewrite is:**

```
RewriteRule ^how-it-works/?$ index.php?action=about&link=howItWorks [NC]
```

index.php GETS "action" and "link" parameters, and then this is where I get lost...

**I am currently using the following:**

```
require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/about.php" );
```

This loads up the about.php template file, which is exactly what I want, but then where do I put the "same page link" of: #HIW? #HIW is a link inside the about.php template file.

Comment: What do you mean by `where do I put the "same page link"`?

Comment: @cheesemacfly: Meaning the # HREF (#HIW in my case). Normally you would put the # HREF at the end of a url, or in a same page link the user clicks on. But because I am loading up a template php file, how do I simulate the user clicking on a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#HIW` in your url is called a [*fragment identifier* in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/intro.html#fragment-uri).

Supposing you are using apache, you can go with (note the `NE` and `R` flags at the end):

```
RewriteRule ^how-it-works/?$ index.php?action=about#HIV [NC,NE,R]
```

(I took of `&link=howItWorks` because I suppose `#HIV` replaces it, if not you can put it back)

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne

Comment: Thank you. This helped solve my challenge. I found that going to domain.com/how-it-works only took me to About Page. But when I go to domain.com/how-it-works#HIW, then it works as expected. In fact, removing in the RewriteRule #HIW and NE, works too.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your URL Rewrite already carries that link information. In this case the `HIW` you mentioned above as the final loading url is `index.php?action=about&link=howItWorks`.

Why don't you `$_GET['link']` inside the about.php and write the output from that result?

I mean, if you want to give the answer from the `about.php` file, you can get the link information with `$_GET[]` and give your desired result information from there.

Comment: how would you "trigger" the link? Normally you would put the # HREF at the end of a url, or in a same page link the user clicks on.

Comment: Well, I was thinking of something like. (in about.php) `if($_GET["link"] =="howItWorks") {echo "html content of that specific page"} `

Answer (score 0):

Expand your rewrite to allow inner links:

```
RewriteRule ^how-it-works/?(#.*)?$ index.php?action=about&link=howItWorks [NC]
```

Please not I don't know if this reg ex works I just typed it out quickly. Please try a few if its not working properly.

It should 'just work' :)

Comment: This doesnt help because the link I want "www.domain.com/how-it-works" already rewrites correctly to "index.php?action=about&link=howItWorks". The issue is how do I reference the same page link when I am requiring a template file.

Comment: What Im saying is, www.domain.com/how-it-works#heading2 does not currently work with your scheme. You need both www.domain.com/how-it-works and www.domain.com/how-it-works#heading2 to get caught by that rule. Is that not a correct understanding?

Comment: Thank you for the help. It seems that I didnt need to add a second Rewrite Rule, which is counter to what I would think too. Here is how I solved my problem: RewriteRule ^how-it-works/?$ index.php?action=about [NC], with the link being domain.com/how-it-works#HIW. This means my other Rewrite Rule: RewriteRule ^about/?$ index.php?action=about [NC] works with the following link: domain.com/about#HIW